# Discord Bot fails to execute simple commands | Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to build a Discord bot; which tells you about the weather condition. But no matter what I did I was unable to execute even the simplest commands such as:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

client = discord.Client()
client.run(token)
```

I just do not get it on Discord side I enter the command "!test hello" to the chat screen and nothing happens. Please help thanks !

Comment: Have you follow all the steps to obtain a token for your bot? Reference: https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you first define a bot using `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")` then add the command to the bot, but then create a new client using `client = discord.Client()` and then run the client.
The problem here is that, you never run the bot, which has the command, so instead of

```py
client = discord.Client()
client.run(token)
```

use

```py
bot.run(token)
```